# Can I use a breadboard to power multiple SG90 servos?

Tags: rcservo, circuit, current

I am planning on using 10 Towerpro SG90 servos, which operate at 4.8V or 6V and can require a maximum stall current of 700ma. If I use a breadboard like this one ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073ZC68QG/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073ZC68QG)), will I be able to supply 5v @700ma to all 10 servos? I am confused because one of the customers asked "What is the maximum current rating on the power supply module?" and the answer was "The Power Supply Module Maximum Output Current: < 700ma." Does that mean each servo that is connected to the breadboard gets 700ma max or does it mean that the current all the servos draw combined is under 700ma?

Comment: yes to `does it mean that the current all the servos draw combined is under 700ma?`

Comment: the breadboard is ok for quickly testing one or two servos ... it is not suitable for use in a final project ... the wires are clamped loosely in the breadboard, which makes the wire connections susceptible to failure and possibly overheating

Comment: @jsotola What would I use in a final project with 10-20 servos in order to distribute the power from a battery? Could you provide any links or model names so I can look into purchasing them? Thanks!

Comment: try using a perfboard or a veroboard and three rows of pin headers ... here is an example ... https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP32-Robot-Using-Servos/ ... add heavy wire to two of the pin rows  .... or this https://diyodemag.com/projects/servo_power

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the links! However, both websites only use 4-5 servos and involve soldering. Is there any way to power 10-20 servos from one/two battery sources without soldering? Also, by thick wire, do you mean like a 14 AWG wire (will my robot be drawing 700ma x 20 [14A] at max?)? What would I use to connect the battery to the servos (meaning - what type of board / device would I connect the battery to, which would regulate the voltage to 5v, and then I could connect 10-20 servos to)? Sorry for all the questions; I am new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Would I get something like this (https://www.amazon.com/Electronics-Salon-tablero-fuente-poder-pines/dp/B01NBU2C64/) or like this (https://www.adafruit.com/product/815)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110800/discussion-between-nothing-and-jsotola).